# Using one CPU by two different people on two different sets of peripherals

Tags: windows-7

I want to use one CPU for access on my laptop as well as another external monitor, keyboard and mouse separately. For example: If I am using my laptop and typing, another person will also be able to use my computer on a different screen (with the same user name or a different one) but will not see what I'm doing.

I have heard of these types of things being done in Africa with Linux, but currently I want to do it Windows.

I am using Windows 7 Home Premium.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: This can't be done with Windows 7 Home Premium.  This can be done with Windows Server though.

Comment: @Ramhound Is there any third-party software that can do it?

Comment: Windows does not have the concept of multiple desktop sessions.  The home versions of Windows do not allow multiple users to be logged in at once.  Windows Server on the other hand does allow, multiple users, provided you have enough seats.

Comment: @Ramhound Isn't there any third-party software, because I don't have Windows Server.

Answer (score 0):

Two options I can think of:

1. You can do it with [virtual machines](https://www.virtualbox.org/), but that would require you to buy a license for each OS.
2. Use the TermServ patch as [demonstrated here](http://www.ehow.com/how_6901286_enable-remote-desktop-sessions-windows.html), which allows you to have multiple concurrent connections to regular stations.
   I've done that once in my organization, but this option is not supported by Microsoft, and might cause unforeseen problems.

If you're willing to consider Linux, than there are many free options, but they probably require more skills.

Comment: I looked at the Termserv patch, but I am wondering on how it works. I don't'want to connect to my computer using Remote desktop, I want to use other peripherals. My computer does not come with Remote desktop. I also have a license for Windows XP, but when I tried to install it in VirtualBox in the past, the installer has been saying that a file is missing. Linux is also an option. I prefer Ubuntu 14.04 (Raring Ringtail). Is there any way to do it with Linux. Do you have a link to Windows XP 32bit installation CD.